# Syntax error for pyspark.sql.functions.from_utc_timestamp(timestamp, tz)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I tried importing `pyspark.sql.functions.from_utc_timestamp(timestamp, tz)` but it always shows an invalid syntax error. How do we use this module to convert set of values in epoch time to UTC in spark?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the code you tried ? You suggested that you imported `pyspark.sql.functions.from_utc_timestamp(timestamp, tz)`, which is a function call and hence invalid python (Syntax Error)

Comment: Oh! then yes i tried import pyspark.sql.functions.from_utc_timestamp(timestamp, tz). I've added the additional code to the question.

Comment: I've answered with some code from the pyspark docs with the appropriate code to import the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some example code (taken from the docs, and modified) to do what you want:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import from_utc_timestamp
>>> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('1997-02-28 10:30:00',)], ['t'])
>>> df.select(from_utc_timestamp(df.t, "PST").alias('t')).collect()
[Row(t=datetime.datetime(1997, 2, 28, 2, 30))]
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. But now i get an error for the line: df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(logLine, ['t'])
saying TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: type 'unicode'
My file contains only 5 values of epoch time.

Comment: What type is logLine ? Is it a array of a tuple of the UTC timestamps ? It should be of the form `[Tuple_of_column_1, Tuple_of_column_2, ...]` where `Tuple_of_column_1` is something like `('1994-05-18 12:30:00', '1997-02-28 10:30:00', '2007-05-02 1:30:00', ...)`.
If it is already a text file, you may want to use `sc.textFile`.
I'd suggest you open new SO questions for questions unrelated to this topic